# How do you create a new HTML page with URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To give some context on what I'm trying to do through a sample:

1. Bill enters some info into a form
2. A new HTML page is dynamically generated which shows the info on the form among content
3. Bill gets a link which can be shared to other people, so they can see what he entered in the form and interact with it

So for example, when you create a new forum post on stackoverflow a new page with the question ID is created (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345/question-title). How do I dynamically generate a new page like this?

Answer (score 2):

The "page creation" must be done at the backend. BY using javascript the most you can do is to send some information which will be used as an input for the creation process. Finally the backend should return the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the technology you want to use. 
I can give you an example in php/symfony.

First you create a database table PAGE , it has some kind of fields: who create, upvotes, title and event reeferences to other table rows like posts, or users. One of those fields are identifiers (new-page-here with you example). Then in symfony you write a route `/pages/{youridentifier}` and you have access to `youridentifier` in a specific controller, now when someone enters this url they invoke a controller. Controler has all the logic. You take all the needed information that is all the fields and render them in a a template and serve it to users.

So basically webpage is created in the backend. If you want to use javascript you can use node.js in backend but that is not the same as front end javascript content generation.

Answer (score 0):

That's a non-trivial question. You're talking about building an application. Conceptually, you need (at a minimum) to 1) save the information entered into the form somewhere, preferably a database 2) create a page that accepts parameters via the URL, looks up the information in the database based on those parameters, and then outputs it in a predefined format. This is often done with languages like PHP and ASP.

There are lots of open source, turn key software applications available that perform various functions (like wikis, forums, etc), so if what you want to do is already available, just install one of those applications and configure it to your needs. There are also open source frameworks available (like CodeIgniter Symfony, Zend, etc) that give you many of the tools you'll need to develop your own custom application.

Answer (score 0):

The pages like your example page 12345/new-page-here are not real pages but build by some server sided framework with content from a database.
So to generate this content you need to save all the data you want to restore later (input from user "a" which will later be accessible by user "b") in some persistent storage (might be a database storage engine like mysql or even phisically files on servers file system) and mark this content to a specific id to recover it later again.
If you now access your page with a link like http://mypage.com/index.php?id=2921 the php script you can access the id by $_GET['id'] and load the specific content from storage to echo it into the html page.

So its not about javascript but only server sided scripting with php or a similar language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn some backend programing language and database.
Like php and mysql.
But if you want to do this with javascript, on way is to use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).
Something useful here to build a CMS with node.js: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/6Cqa9waVAIY

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try something like this before, but I think you can experiment with peer to peer architecture where you will set up dynamic container and update it through socket connection. Take a look to

http://socket.io/

http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/